# How do you properly address another scripts function?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to call a function called dieAnim() in one script from another script, called Magnum.

This is in my Fire function in the Magnum script:

```
if (hit.collider.tag == "Alien1")
{
    Alien.dieAnim();
}
```

In the Alien script:

```
public void dieAnim()
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Everytime i try to run this, it says Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 1):

To run this more efficiently do

```
if(hit.collider.CompareTag("Alien1")){
    //either
    Destroy(hit.gameObject);
    //or if there is logic in dieAnim()
    hit.collider.GetComponent<Alien>().dieAnim();
}
```

The reason your code was not working was because you were calling the dieAnim() function as if it were on a static component. That means you were trying to call it on all scripts basically. You have to have a reference to that instance of the alien that you hit. The CompareTag is just a special function that allows you to compare tags of gameobjects more quickly and efficiently than a string == string comparison.

Answer (score 0):

In the above it looks like you're trying to call dieAnim() from the Class name of Alien

You'll want to use

```
hit.collider.gameobject.GetComponent<desiredcomponent>().dieAnim();
```

In this you're accessing the instance of the Alien class as a component.

Edit for clarity.

In the editor when you add a script you're adding a new monobehavior. These are attached to a game object as components. So when you want to access one, you have the access the components of the game object.

So in your case to get the other script you need to call get component on your the game object your colliider hit. The tag is also attached to the game object itself

Comment: Im confused... what syntax would this be used in? It wouldn't work as its own line

Comment: In the above where you check the tag. You can access the game object you hit by using hit.collider.gameobject. to get the script from the game object using get component with the class name of your script in <> if you get component not found, the item you hit doesn't have that component

Comment: Thanks but I think the other guy had the best answer :P

Comment: It solves your use case but not your problem of how do I call the function of a component in another gameobject

Answer (score 0):

Just re-write your code to the following

```
if (hit.collider.tag == "Alien1")
{
    hit.collider.GetComponent<Alien>().dieAnim();
}
```

But if the the *only* thing that dieAnim is doing is destroying the alien that was hit, you don't need to call a function inside of another script for that - that's *overkill*.

Just do this

```
if (hit.collider.tag == "Alien1")
{
     Destroy(hit.gameObject);
}
```

Comment: Sorry! Didn't check ;-; Thanks tho I think that comment is the problem. Everytime I post here its the dumb answer